# Would a XMLHttpRequest handle abitrary TCP stream responses?

Tags: javascript, tcp, xmlhttprequest

If a TCP server ignores the HTTP request issued by a XMLHttpRequest and just answers

```
Hello world
```

for example, how would the browser react, and would there be any method to receive the `Hello world`?

Answer (score 0):

In theory a proper response from the web server is expected, i.e. HTTP header and HTTP body. In practice there is the old HTTP 0.9 protocol from 1991 which does not have a HTTP header yet. This protocol is still supported in many browsers which means that a response from the server without HTTP header will be handled by these browsers as a HTTP 0.9 response and everything from the start of the response up to the close of the connection will be interpreted as the HTTP body. HTTP 0.9 is currently supported by IE, Edge, Firefox and most versions of Chrome/Opera (which are essentially the same). Support is restricted in Safari and it will be removed in Chrome/Opera in the next time.
 For more details and how HTTP 0.9 can be misused see https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/OdKnpLlvVUo and http://noxxi.de/research/http-evader-explained-1-http09.html